# Batchnormalization nodes wrongfully linked with each other

Tags: keras, tensorboard

I'm training a Keras network using BatchNormalization layers and saw a strange thing looking at the TensorBoard graph. My network consists of a stack of 1D convolutions followed by BatchNormalization layers. Most of the graph seems fine, but the very first BatchNormalization layer is - according to TensorBoard - sending information to all other BatchNormalization layers. Is this normal?

Here's the output of the network according to Keras `model.summary()`

```
| Layer (type)                    | Output Shape      | Param # | Connected to        |
|---------------------------------|-------------------|---------|---------------------|
| pt_cloud_0 (InputLayer)         | (None, None, 39)  | 0       |                     |
| pt_cloud_1 (InputLayer)         | (None, None, 39)  | 0       |                     |
| conv1d_0_0 (Conv1D)             | (None, None, 64)  | 2560    | pt_cloud_0[0][0]    |
| conv1d_1_0 (Conv1D)             | (None, None, 64)  | 2560    | pt_cloud_1[0][0]    |
| batchnorm_0_0 (BatchNormalizati | (None, None, 64)  | 256     | conv1d_0_0[0][0]    |
| batchnorm_1_0 (BatchNormalizati | (None, None, 64)  | 256     | conv1d_1_0[0][0]    |
| conv1d_0_1 (Conv1D)             | (None, None, 64)  | 4160    | batchnorm_0_0[0][0] |
| conv1d_1_1 (Conv1D)             | (None, None, 64)  | 4160    | batchnorm_1_0[0][0] |
| batchnorm_0_1 (BatchNormalizati | (None, None, 64)  | 256     | conv1d_0_1[0][0]    |
| batchnorm_1_1 (BatchNormalizati | (None, None, 64)  | 256     | conv1d_1_1[0][0]    |
| conv1d_0_2 (Conv1D)             | (None, None, 316) | 20540   | batchnorm_0_1[0][0] |
| conv1d_1_2 (Conv1D)             | (None, None, 316) | 20540   | batchnorm_1_1[0][0] |
| batchnorm_0_2 (BatchNormalizati | (None, None, 316) | 1264    | conv1d_0_2[0][0]    |
| batchnorm_1_2 (BatchNormalizati | (None, None, 316) | 1264    | conv1d_1_2[0][0]    |
| conv1d_0_3 (Conv1D)             | (None, None, 316) | 100172  | batchnorm_0_2[0][0] |
| conv1d_1_3 (Conv1D)             | (None, None, 316) | 100172  | batchnorm_1_2[0][0] |
| aux_in (InputLayer)             | (None, 46)        | 0       | 0                   |
| batchnorm_0_3 (BatchNormalizati | (None, None, 316) | 1264    | conv1d_0_3[0][0]    |
| batchnorm_1_3 (BatchNormalizati | (None, None, 316) | 1264    | conv1d_1_3[0][0]    |
| aux_dense_0 (Dense)             | (None, 384)       | 18048   | aux_in[0][0]        |
| global_max_0 (GlobalMaxPooling1 | (None, 316)       | 0       | batchnorm_0_3[0][0] |
| global_max_1 (GlobalMaxPooling1 | (None, 316)       | 0       | batchnorm_1_3[0][0] |
| aux_dense_1 (Dense)             | (None, 384)       | 147840  | aux_dense_0[0][0]   |
| concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     | (None, 1016)      | 0       | global_max_0[0][0]  |
|                                 |                   |         | global_max_1[0][0]  |
|                                 |                   |         | aux_dense_1[0][0]   |
| dense_0 (Dense)                 | (None, 384)       | 390528  | concatenate_1[0][0] |
| dropout_0 (Dropout)             | (None, 384)       | 0       | dense_0[0][0]       |
| dense_1 (Dense)                 | (None, 384)       | 147840  | dropout_0[0][0]     |
| prediction (Dense)              | (None, 101)       | 38885   | dense_1[0][0]       |
```

And here's (part of) the graph shown in TensorBoard [image: graph]
(If the image is not visible, please go to this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIf6P.jpg)
Zoomed version: [image: zoomed_graph] or this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBhDj.jpg

The red-outlined layer is the very first batch normalization layer I made in the network (batchnorm_0_0). I don't know much about the inner workings of a batchnormalization layer but I find it odd that it is linked to all other BN-layers, while those other BN-layers do not (they just are connected to the input/output I assigned them).
I'm wondering if this is a bug in my code, in keras, or maybe in TensorBoard?

**Update:** model's code below; it's written in a way I can easily experiment with the number of convolution layers/filters, etc... but should be rather explanatory.

```
def _build(self, conv_filter_counts, dense_counts, dense_dropout_rates=None):
    """
    Builds the model. The model will have the following architecture:
      (1) [Per pointcloud] N 1D convolution layers (with possibly different depths) followed by BatchNormalization
                           layers.
      (2) [Per pointcloud] A global max pooling layer (calculating a 'global feature' of the point cloud).
      (3) [Once] M dense layers (with possibly different amounts of neurons), optionally followed by DropOut layers.
      (4) [Once] A final dense layer with `self.class_count` neurons and softmax activation.

    Arguments:
      conv_filter_counts: A list (length N) containing the succesive 1D convolution filter depths in (1)
      dense_counts: A list (length M) containing the amount of succesive neurons in (3)
      dense_dropout_rates: Optional. If specified, must be a list of length M containing the dropout rates
                           for each corresponding dense layer specified by `dense_counts`. Individual entries
                           can be set to None to disable dropout.
                           If not specified, dropout is applied nowhere.
    """
    inputs = [Input(shape=(None, self.pt_dim), name='pt_cloud_{}'.format(i)) for i in range(self.input_count)]
    if self.aux_input_count > 0:
        aux_input = Input(shape=(self.aux_input_count,), name='aux_in')

    if self.spatial_subnet:
        # Predict and apply spatial transform for each pointcloud.
        spatial_transforms = [transform_subnet(i, [64, 128, 256], [256, 64]) for i in inputs]
        inputs_tr = [apply_transform_layer(i, tr, self.pt_dim) for i, tr in zip(inputs, spatial_transforms)]
    else:
        inputs_tr = inputs

    global_feats = []
    for i, input_pts in enumerate(inputs_tr):
       x = input_pts

       # Convolution stack
       for j, c in enumerate(conv_filter_counts):
           x = Convolution1D(c, 1, activation='relu', name='conv1d_{}_{}'.format(i, j))(x)
           x = BatchNormalization(name='batchnorm_{}_{}'.format(i, j))(x)

       global_feats += [GlobalMaxPooling1D(name='global_max_{}'.format(i))(x)]

    # Concatenate features and possibly auxiliary input
    if self.aux_input_count > 0:
        x = aux_input

        # Create a dense subnetwork just for the auxiliary inpuy
        for i, (c, d) in enumerate(zip(dense_counts, dense_dropout_rates)):
            x = Dense(c, activation='relu', name='aux_dense_{}'.format(i))(x)

        x = Concatenate()(global_feats + [x])
    elif len(global_feats) > 1:
        x = Concatenate()(global_feats)
    else:
        x = global_feats[0]

    # Dense stack with optional dropout
    if dense_dropout_rates is None:
        dense_dropout_rates = [None] * len(dense_counts)

    for i, (c, d) in enumerate(zip(dense_counts, dense_dropout_rates)):
        x = Dense(c, activation='relu', name='dense_{}'.format(i))(x)
        if d is not None:
            x = Dropout(rate=d, name='dropout_{}'.format(i))(x)

    # Final prediction
    prediction = Dense(self.class_count, activation='softmax', name='prediction')(x)

    # Link all up in a model
    if self.aux_input_count > 0:
        inputs.append(aux_input)

    if len(inputs) == 1:
        inputs = inputs[0]

    return Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=prediction)
```

Kind regards,

steven

Comment: You should include your models' source code because that is where the problem might be.

Comment: I thought the output of `summary()` would already give you a good indication on how the model was built up, but have added the code just to make sure you have indeed all the information. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: The thing is I don't see in the summary that all batchnorm layers are connected to the first, and neither in the code.

Comment: Correct.. And that's my question. It is not connected, so why does the Tensorboard graph show it as connected?

Comment: I don't know, and also I cannot read what the connection between batchnorm says in your image, too low resolution.

Comment: It says '2 tensors'. I assume that will be the mu and sigma of the BN layer, but no idea why they should be fed to the rest. I've updated the link to the full PNG as output  by tensorboard and also added a zoomed-in screenshot of the first BN layer.

Comment: I got the same situation and the same question here. This happens regardless of how big is my network. One thing in my mind is that, maybe this is just the visualization hiccup from tensorboard because model.summary() + the code did not indicate any connections. But I am not sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

A cautious answer to my own question, @Mike, I think (hope?) this is indeed a bug on the tensorboard side as I can't explain it otherwise.

I plotted the architecture using `keras.utils.plot_model` and this also doesn't show any links between the BatchNormalization layers.